# Cannot open database “Mail” requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have created a winform application and now I a want to create a setup file for it.

For this I change my database location and put into my project in folder data, but after I change my connection string it's showing me an error that cannot open mail

Here it's my connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\Data\Mail.mdf;Initial Catalog=Mail;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Please help me I am stuck.

Comment: is your database in sql server named `.\SQLEXPRESS` or a file stored in `\Data` folder?

Answer (score 0):

That error would usually occur if there is no file Mail.mdf in the Data folder under the standard data directory for SQL Express.

How are you setting the standard data directory? (Or is it just the default), and are you definitely deploying the file into that folder? Finally, if it really is there, are the permissions on the file and folder appropriate?